# Pgfplot - Plotting with arrows to indicate direction between two consecutive data points

Tags: pgfplots, arrows

Is there any easy way to automatically create arrow between two consecutive data points read from a table? (in addition to adding a mark). See attached picture.[image]

For large data set, I find adding node to be too tedious.

MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=0.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{9cm}
\def\axisdefaultheight{6cm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[compat=newest, xlabel=Premixed air flow rate (SLPM), ylabel=$p'_{rms}$ (Pa),xtick pos=left]
\pgfplotstableread{sa} \mydata;
\addplot[only marks,mark=*] table [x = x, y =y] {\mydata};
\draw[->] (axis cs:1, 2) -- (axis cs:2, 4);
\draw[->] (axis cs:2, 4) -- (axis cs:3, 3);
\draw[->] (axis cs:3, 3) -- (axis cs:4, 1.5);
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The file 'sa' contains the data

```
x   y
1   2
2   4
3   3
4   1.5
```

In the plot produced, the mark shrouds the arrow and also it is tedious to add it for each pair of cs:
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE that shows what you have done so far and what the `table` looks like that contains your data. Thank you!

Comment: @StefanBraun: I have edited my question to include MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes that the `sa` file is tab separated.

```
\documentclass[margin=0.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{9cm}
\def\axisdefaultheight{6cm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}
\DTLsettabseparator
\DTLloaddb[noheader=false]{coordinates1}{sa}
\DTLmaketabspace


\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[compat=newest, xlabel=Premixed air flow rate (SLPM), ylabel=$p'_{rms}$ (Pa),xtick pos=left,ybar=0]
\pgfplotstableread{sa} \mydata;
\addplot[mark options={blue,solid},mark=*,only marks] table [x = x, y =y] {\mydata};
\pgfplotsextra{
\def\xA{0}
\def\yA{0}
\DTLforeach*{coordinates1}{\xB=x, \yB=y}{%
    \DTLiffirstrow{
    }{
    \draw[-latex,shorten >=0.05cm,] (axis cs:\xA,\yA) -- (axis cs:\xB,\yB);
    }
    \let\xA\xB
    \let\yA\yB
}
}
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

This solution uses the `datatool` package and requires a comma separated version of your data. The first data point is the (xA,yA) in the tex code.

```
\documentclass[margin=0.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{filecontents}{sa}
x   y
1   2
2   4
3   3
4   1.5
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{sa2}
x,y
2,4
3,3
4,1.5
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{9cm}
\def\axisdefaultheight{6cm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}
\DTLloaddb[noheader=false]{coordinates1}{sa2}


\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[compat=newest, xlabel=Premixed air flow rate (SLPM), ylabel=$p'_{rms}$ (Pa),xtick pos=left,ybar=0]
\pgfplotstableread{sa} \mydata;
\addplot[mark options={blue,solid},mark=*,only marks] table [x = x, y =y] {\mydata};
\pgfplotsextra{
\def\xA{1}
\def\yA{2}
\DTLforeach*{coordinates1}{\xB=x, \yB=y}{%
    \draw[-latex,shorten >=0.05cm,] (axis cs:\xA,\yA) -- (axis cs:\xB,\yB);
    \let\xA\xB
    \let\yA\yB
}
}
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory have comma separated data? Is there any way around it?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Check my edited answer

Comment: I ran into problem again. I had to do some processing with the data. so for plotting, I used `\addplot [mark options={blue,solid},mark=*,only marks]  table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}/100, y expr=\thisrowno{2}]`. But  the code for arrow requires the rows to have a header x and y. This is giving me an error. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Can you duplicate your file and put a x,y header in the second one?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar looks like a new question for me ... especially because I do not know the error message of `an error`.