# How to connect coordinates with arrows in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I have a set of coordinates, which I am plotting with pgfplots. Rather than connect them with a simple line, I would like to connect them with arrows.

I have tried using `\addplot[->]`, however, this only puts an arrow at the final coordinate. I want an arrow for each line segment connecting the coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[->] coordinates {
     (0, 1)
     (2, 4)
     (4, 10)
     (3, 6)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316583/ has one possible method, but there may well be other.

Answer (score 1):

Try this trivial method:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[->] coordinates {
                (0, 1)
                (2, 4)
                };
        \addplot[->] coordinates {
            (2, 4)
            (4, 10)
                };
            \addplot[->] coordinates {
                (4, 10)
                (3, 6)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]